# How to use @Html.PartialView("XXX") in Jquery function?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, razor

I have a function that updates a div with raw HTML. However, the raw HTML is in another .CSHTML document.

My function is:

```
function Demo(){
$('#ContainerDiv').html('@Html.Partial("MyPartialView")');
}
```

For some reason, whenever I include my partial view within the function, my console shows that it is unable to locate the document.

As soon as I remove the @Html.PartialView("MyPartialView") and include it in the body of the document, it loads fine.

Any ideas on why this would not be working, or a better way of doing this?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: You're trying to render the contents of an ASP.NET partial view into another div, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your partial view probably contains line breaks, which results in multi-line string literals, which aren't valid in js. I see two options: Render the partial view in a hidden div when the page loads and move it to `#ContainerDiv` when you need to, or use ajax to get the content later.

Comment: Not only line breaks, but all kinds of other unescaped (and unencoded) characters. Imagine copying a block of console output back into a string literal in your C# code. It's not gonna work.

Comment: It's a small partial view, it actually is pretty clean, but there are defineatly line breaks in there....Ill give you the answer as when SO lets me

Answer (score 0):

You could call an action and then populate a container with the resulting HTML.

For example:

Action:

```
public PartialViewResult GetPartial() {
    return PartialView("MyPartialView");
}
```

JQuery:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("GetPartial")').done(function(response){
    $('#ContainerDiv').html(response)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always used `.load()` and the url to the partial view.  Like so:

```
function Demo(){
$('#ContainerDiv').load('@Html.Raw(Url.Action("MyPartialView"))');
}
```

Edit: Forgot to change `.html()` to `.load()`